# force type with annotation in Java

Tags: java, annotations

Is it possible to force a type for annotated member ?

e.g

```
  // legal (implements my interface Arrayable{ toArray(); })
  @ArrayableAnnotation
  Set someData;

  // not legal, should be detected by the compiler 
  @ArrayableAnnotation
  Integer someNumber;
```

To be more clear:

1. I want to mark some members to be serialized using my annotation.
2. I want to force that only members that are implementing MySrialize will be allowed to be marked by  my annotation.

Thanks.

Comment: You can, using AnnotationProcessors, but it doesn't really do anything for you - the code `someData.toArray()` will compile or not compile regardless of the existence of your annotation.  Why not just rely on the `Collection` interface?

Comment: I've added more info to describe what I need. specifically I would like the compiler to help me.

Answer (score 0):

What you ask is too specific and can't be achieved with default annotations.

However you can write your own custom annotations to force whatever you want with [apt](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/apt/GettingStarted.html) (annotation processing tool).

Comment: looks interesting. I will check it out. Thanks.